# Electrostatic force by non-conducting 3D body

Tags: electrostatics, dielectric

[image: diagram]
A test charge $q$ is placed in front of a non-conducting sphere of charge $Q$ at a distance $r$ from the centre of the sphere. We consider the sphere as a 3d-symmetrical body, we write the electric force on a test charge $$F = \frac{Qq}{4πε_0x^2}$$ where $ε_0$ is the permittivity of air.

But in the sphere there are many electrons. Each of the electrons have a different distance from test charge. So that in all such cases between electron and test charge there is some part of non-conducting sphere of dielectric constant $k$.

If we consider this now, the force exerted by any small charge at a distance $x$ we can write $$F'=\frac{q\,dq}{4π(kε_0)x^2}.$$

Here, clearly we can see that force is decreased. But in all books and teachers can't consider this.

Can you explain me why this dielectric constant is not considered in the equation and derivation?

Answer (score 0):

In the general result of Coulomb's Law i.e. $$F=\frac{q_1q_2}{(4π\epsilon_0)r^2}$$ the surrounding medium is considered as vacuum. Also, many questions on this topic also have vacuum as medium. So they don't generally consider the dielectric constant $k$.

However, the book which I used, "Understanding Physics" by D.C. Pandey, has clearly marked out these point. [Here it is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jTWQ6.jpg).

Comment: There is a vaccum out side but, what about sphere's dielectric constant